# How does one properly strip coaxial cable to nonstandard strip lengths?

Tags: cables, coax, crimp, strip

For my job, I need to put SHV connectors on a couple lengths of RG-59. I have the cable, the connector, and the crimping tool, but I've hit a snag: I don't have the slightest idea how to properly strip the cable! The datasheet gives me some lengths, but every coaxial stripping tool I can find either has a preset strip length intended for a more common connector (BNC or F, mostly) or an adjustable strip length, but only less than about 3/4 of an inch--and SHV (being a high-voltage connector) requires a total strip length of over an inch to achieve proper isolation distance.

I managed to get one connector crimped on by stripping the cable with very careful application of side cutters and an x-acto knife, but I'm sure there's a better way out there. How do people normally strip coax for unusual connectors?

Comment: Side cutters and X-Acto knife here. OK, and a bit of practice.

Comment: Side cutters and a pocket knife.

Comment: @JRE Well, that's a little annoying! I would have expected there'd be foolproof tools that just cut one layer at a time or something. I'm enough of a fool that I'd want something foolproof.